# How to create multiple files in SAS?

Tags: sas

I am trying to write a macro that should create multiple external `html` files . Here is my code

```
%macro createFiles;
%let name = Jupiter*Mercury*Venus;
%let htmlTxt1 = <html><h1>Hello To ; 
%let htmlTxt2 = </h1></html>  ; 
%let i = 1 ; 
%let thisName = %scan(&name., &i.,"*") ; 
%do %while (&thisName. ne ) ; 

filename thisFile "C:\Users\owner\Desktop\&thisName.html";
call execute ('data  _null_; file &thisFile; put &htmlTxt1 || &thisName || &htmlTxt2; run; ') ;

%let i = %eval(&i + 1  )  ;
%let thisName = %scan(&name.,&i.,"*"); 
%end ;
%mend ; 

%createFiles
```

However, it does not work .    Please help me

Thanks

Comment: I think you've mixed up your ts and name macro variables, name is never created.  Run it with option mprint on and that'll help debug.

Comment: There's also no data step. I think you may be mixing call execute and macro code incorrectly.

Comment: Thank you. I corrected the `ts` typo. I am sure i missing something with the data step inside the macro syntax

Comment: Can you please state clearly what you are trying to do, and what is happening instead? What you are asking is too unclear and/or too broad at the minute. Thanks

Comment: No need for call execute, that is for executing inside a data step. And, you need quotes around the text in the put. The %let thisName only is needed once, after the %do %while, delete the one before.

Comment: Can anybody correct my `call execute` statement ? This is the best I can come up with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly a combination of typo's and syntax errors. SAS also has the ODS HTML destination which would be easier to use to create HTML files in my opinion.

```
%macro createFiles;
%let name = Jupiter*Mercury*Venus;
%let htmlTxt1 = <html><h1>Hello To ; 
%let htmlTxt2 = </h1></html>  ; 
%let i = 1 ; 
%let thisName = %scan(&name., &i.,"*") ; 
%do %while (&thisName. ne ) ; 

filename thisFile "C:\temp\&thisName..html";

data  _null_; 
file thisFile; 
put "&htmlTxt1 || &thisName || &htmlTxt2"; 
run; 

%let i = %eval(&i + 1  )  ;
%let thisName = %scan(&name.,&i.,"*"); 
%end ;
%mend ; 

%createFiles
```

Comment: +1 Thank you. But it still does not work. **I copied the code as it is.** I also tried to modify `file thisFile` to `file &thisFile` . . and there are no files created and no error thrown

Comment: I opened a new instance of SAS, and it worked! I have no idea why it was not working in the old session ? Thank you for your answer !!!

Comment: Glad worked, but you should really look into ODS HTML to create these files instead for you.